# Make XAML Border Height Change On Internal Item Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resize

I know that I can create two different borders for my item groups and use my visibility converter to hide/unhide as needed, but was hoping I can do this a little cleaner...

I have a group of items (mostly labels and a progress bar) and depending on if my worker is in progress or not, I hide/unhide what is needed to display.

The problem seems to be that I have a border around the entire set of items (more items are shown when in progress) and the height set to auto for the border. However when I hide the larger group of items my border does not resize.

Is there a way to get this desired result with a single border... or do I need to just bind another border that is smaller in size?

(Also along the same lines would this also allow my grid to resize since this is a control so there a multiple instances on the same page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing Visibility.Hidden.  Try Visibility.Collapsed

Comment: I am using BooleanToVisibilityConverter... shouldn't that collapse by default?

Comment: Sorry just realized one of my items was not going invisible... the collapsing works great now. Thanks!